# jq: error (at file.json:xy): Cannot index string/array with string "string"

Tags: json, csv, jq

***I have an json file containing 1 array of thousand documents.***
I need to convert file to csv format with specific values only.

Each document can have another combination of fields or sub-documents or, (and this is what makes me an problem), sometimes value of a field is array of subdocuments, in the other case it's value is just subcdoc  or field just does not exists.

My goal is to extract value of **.meta.dev.devId** (if field does not exists, then use empty column in csv.
Docs e.g. in the base array:

```
1st doc:
{ 
    "docId": "some_hex", 
    "bin": { 
        "field": "value", 
        "length": "123456"
    },
    "item": "item",
    "meta": { 
        "date": "dateFnc(123456789)",
        "name": "name",
        "dev": {
            "devId": "987654321",
            "devName": "name"
        },
    "type": "type1" 
    }
}
```

```
2nd doc:
{ 
    "docId": "some_hex", 
    "bin": { 
        "field": "value", 
        "length": "123456"
    },
    "item": "item",
    "meta": { 
        "date": "dateFnc(123456789)",
        "name": "name",
        "dev": [ {
            "devId": "987654321",
            "devName": "name"
        } ],
    "type": "type1" 
    }
}
```

```
3rd doc:
{ 
    "docId": "some_hex", 
    "bin": { 
        "field": "value", 
        "length": "123456"
    },
    "item": "item",
    "meta": { 
        "date": "dateFnc(123456789)",
        "name": "name",
    "type": "type1" 
    }
}
```

***Command 1:***
`jq -r '.[] | [.docId, .item, .meta.date, .meta.name, .meta.dev[]?.devId] | @csv' file.json > file.csv`

***Result 1:***
*Cannot index string with string "devId"*

***Command 2:***
`jq -r '.[] | [.docId, .item, .meta.date, .meta.name, .meta.dev[].devId] | @csv' file.json > file.csv`

***Result 2:***
*Cannot iterate over null (null)*

***Command 3:***
`jq -r '.[] | [.docId, .item, .meta.date, .meta.name, .meta.dev.devId] | @csv' file.json > file.csv`

***Result 3:***
*Cannot index array with string "devId"*

How I understand commands:

.[] | [.meta.dev.devId] → Expected value: "string"

.[] | [.meta.dev[].devId] → Expected value: [array]

.[] | [.meta.dev[]?.devId] → Expected value: [array] or not an array

Comment: Please add the desired output!

Comment: What is the desired output and can you please include your JSON document with a few (<10) elements in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could traverse to `.meta.dev`, then filter by type using the [shortcuts](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L54-L64) `objects` and `arrays`, combined with a type-specific action (e.g. extracting the first array item's field with `arrays[0].devId`). If `.meta.dev` didn't exist, it would yield `null`, so you could use the same technique to provide for a default value (e.g. `nulls | "missing"`).

```bash
< file.json > file.csv jq -r '.[] | [
  .docId, .item, .meta.date, .meta.name,
  (.meta.dev | objects.devId, arrays[0].devId, (nulls | "missing"))
] | @csv'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mDUKU9pcr3H)

---

Alternatively [sic], you could use the [Destructuring Alternative Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#DestructuringAlternativeOperator%3A%3F%2F%2F) `?//` to provide for the different structures expected (`[{$devId}]` or `{$devId}`):

```bash
< file.json > file.csv jq -r '.[] | [
  .docId, .item, .meta.date, .meta.name,
  (.meta.dev as [{$devId}] ?// {$devId} | $devId) // "missing"
] | @csv'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cBYk9uD4HdJ)

---

Contents of `file.csv`:

```
"some_hex","item","dateFnc(123456789)","name","987654321"
"some_hex","item","dateFnc(123456789)","name","987654321"
"some_hex","item","dateFnc(123456789)","name","missing"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if-then-else-end` on the `type` to `map()` over `devId` when `dev` is an array, or just use `.devId` if it's not:

```
.[] | [ .meta?.dev? | if type == "array" then map(.devId)[] else .devId? end ] | @csv
```

---

Result with an array with your 3 input docs:

```
"\"987654321\""
"\"987654321\""
""
```

---

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/k0eaEasSXq8)